# Failure to push updates to Heroku, possibly related to TipTap or Tailwind

Tags: heroku, tailwind-css, mern, tiptap

I haven't been able to update this heroku website for 2 months. The latest Heroku build log is below after a quick summary of my attempts. I've tried a dozen different things and spent hours upon hours trying to figure it out. Below are some highlights.

It's a full-stack MERN project with Tailwind for styling and TipTap for a WYSIWYG text editor. The frontend and backend scripts run fine on my local machine and the project pushed just fine for a few months. I've tried multiple things to fix it with no luck, though each time I do, the error messages in the long Heroku script change somewhat. First, the errors appeared to indicated it was TipTap, which made sense because it was very beta when I first made this, but I've updated it, and TipTap is out of beta (I also tried completely removing it from the project). Another time, Tailwind seemed to be the issue, so I tried updating it and downgrading it. I've checked the docs for recent updates. I've tried updating everything else, even downgrading several too, I've deleted and reinstalled the node modules and package-lock.json a million times, etc. The latest builds indicate an issue with sass, despite the fact I'm not using it, but something appears to keep adding sass to the package-lock.json. I'm at a complete loss to be honest.

Here are some tidbits of the errors in the heroku build log. SO has a word limit, so I can't post the entire thing. If there's a way, please let me know, and I will be happy to do so.

```
...

../src/fibers.cc:930:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
  930 | NODE_MODULE(fibers, init)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [fibers.target.mk:122: Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o] Error 1
       make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_9f8161ac/client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fibers/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_9f8161ac/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:201:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1104-aws
gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_9f8161ac/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_9f8161ac/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_9f8161ac/client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v19.9.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'` 
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
sh: 1: nodejs: not found

...

../node_modules/nan/nan_callbacks_12_inl.h:14:6: warning: ‘void IndexDeleterCallbackWrapper(uint32_t, const v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Boolean>&)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
   14 | void IndexDeleterCallbackWrapper(
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [binding.target.mk:131: Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_9f8161ac/client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1104-aws
gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_9f8161ac/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_9f8161ac/client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_9f8161ac/client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v19.9.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
       make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_9f8161ac/client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/node-sass/build'
Build failed with error code: 1
       
       > @swc/core@1.3.61 postinstall /tmp/build_9f8161ac/client/node_modules/tailwindcss/node_modules/@swc/core
       > node postinstall.js

...

       
       > @swc/core@1.3.61 postinstall /tmp/build_9f8161ac/client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest/node_modules/@jest/core/node_modules/@swc/core
       > node postinstall.js
       
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1104-aws
npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_9f8161ac/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_9f8161ac/node_modules/.bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v19.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
npm ERR! path /tmp/build_9f8161ac/client/node_modules/tailwindcss/node_modules/@types/node/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! errno -20
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/tmp/build_9f8161ac/client/node_modules/tailwindcss/node_modules/@types/node/package.json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/build_9f8161ac/client/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1104-aws
npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_9f8161ac/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_9f8161ac/node_modules/.bin/npm" "run" "install-client"
npm ERR! node v19.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! laz-blog@1.0.0 install-client: `cd client && npm install`
npm ERR! Exit status 236
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the laz-blog@1.0.0 install-client script 'cd client && npm install'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the laz-blog package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cd client && npm install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs laz-blog
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls laz-blog
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/build_9f8161ac/npm-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```